# Emacs : "set default font" and init.el

Tags: emacs, fonts

I want to set up my starting default font.
I choose a font in Options --> set Default Font. then I save it with Options --> Save Options.

This writes at the end of my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file :

```
 (custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "white" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant italic :weight bold :height 241 :width normal :foundry "microsoft" :family "Trebuchet MS" "Courier New" :foundry "monotype" :slant normal :weight bold :height 240 :width normal "Courier New"))))
```

When starting emacs again, the selected font is not loaded. And there is no problem with the init.d file, as reported in `*Messages*` or by --debug-init.
It seems the mechanism by which "set default font" finds fonts and init.d finds fonts are different ...

What do I do wrong ?
Running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Emacs 24

Comment: I find the occurrence of `"Courier New"` strange. Does it work if you remove both occurrences?

Comment: Also, make sure that you only have `(custom-set-faces...)` occur only once in your init file, as per the comment in your quote above.

Comment: By the way -- I assume by `init.d` you actually mean `.emacs.d/init.el` ?

Comment: Ooops !! Absolutely !

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Emacs 27.1)

```
;; Set default font
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Courier New"
                    :height 120
                    :weight 'normal
                    :width 'normal)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set it in your init.el file the following:

(set-default-font "Inconsolata 12")

or monaco font

(set-default-font "Monaco 12")

Comment: I get: "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function set-default-font)"